# Form Validation Not Resetting After Failing Validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm using a small script to validate a postcode, which works and stops the user entering an invalid password, but when an invalid post code is entered you then can't submit a correct entry. For example, if I enter 'ST' I get the message telling me the postcode is invalid, so without refreshing the page manually I enter 'ST6 1SA' (which is a valid Stoke postcode) and I can't submit the form, I just keep getting the invalid tool tip advising me the post code is not in the correct format.

JS:

```
<script>
   // Validate the postcode before it's sent
   (function () {
      var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode-entry');
      var wrapper = document.getElementById('validation');
      var notify = document.createElement('div');
      var mnisLookup = document.getElementById('mnis-results');
      var matchingClients = document.getElementById('matching-clients');
      var postcodeWrapper = document.getElementById('postcode-wrapper');

      notify.id = 'notify';
      notify.style.display = 'none';
      wrapper.appendChild(notify);

      postcode.addEventListener('invalid', function (event) {
         if (!event.target.validity.valid) {
         notify.textContent = 'Please enter a valid postcode e.g. ST1, ST1 4BJ';
         notify.className = 'error';
         notify.style.display = 'block';

         postcode.className = 'form-control invalid';
      }                
   });
})();
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="postcode-wrapper" class="form-horizontal">
        <div id="postcode-lookup" class="form-group">
            <label for="postcode-entry" class="col-sm-1">Postcode:</label>
            <div id="postcode-entry-wrapper" class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" pattern="^(([gG][iI][rR] {0,}0[aA]{2})|((([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][0-9][a-hjkstuwA-HJKSTUW])|([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y][0-9][abehmnprv-yABEHMNPRV-Y])))( {0,}[0-9][abd-hjlnp-uw-zABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})?))$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Invalid Post Code Format ')" class="form-control" id="postcode-entry" placeholder="Enter your postcode" name="Postcode" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input id="search" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
            <div id="validation" class="col-sm-7"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Just a quick note that may affect how the page is refreshing, this is inside an MVC Razor page and wrapped with `Html.BeginForm` - not sure if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 4):

While debugging your code, i found that the `event.target.validity.valid` was returning false even if the input was valid e.g. 'ST6 1SA'. This was occuring because it does not update the custom validation for the new input and the previous state persists even after entering the valid input.

So to update and reset the previous validation, you have to reset `setCustomValidity('')` on input change, i.e. `oninput="setCustomValidity('')"`

Please replace this code:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^(([gG][iI][rR] {0,}0[aA]{2})|((([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][0-9][a-hjkstuwA-HJKSTUW])|([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y][0-9][abehmnprv-yABEHMNPRV-Y])))( {0,}[0-9][abd-hjlnp-uw-zABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})?))$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Invalid Post Code Format ')" class="form-control" id="postcode-entry" placeholder="Enter your postcode" name="Postcode" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
```

Comment: That postcode is correct if it's added before validation failing and returns the expected result

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf Hi, I found the solution and updated the answer. Please mark as helpful if it solves your problem

Comment: Thanks, it is absolutely insane that this is necessary. What on earth is happening to web development??