# Reset individual form field's custom validity state

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a basic form field that is valid in all conditions including when empty:

```
<input id="example1" name="example" type="text" />
```

In some unrelated (to this question) conditions I use JavaScript to mark this element as invalid:

```
id_('example1').setCustomValidity('All aboard the nope train!');
id_('example1').reportValidity();
```

I won't post the other code because it is perfectly valid if this form field is empty when the full form is submitted.

How do I reset the validity state of this *specific* form field without attempting to submit the entire form?

I have attempted `id_('post_custom_selector').validity.valid = true;` though it did not work and with all the methods for [ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) being read-only I suspect that if I'm not missing anything else looking at the methods for the [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) then I may be stuck having to duplicate the node and replace it.

Absolutely no frameworks or libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Form Validation Not Resetting After Failing Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813685/form-validation-not-resetting-after-failing-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first parameter for `setCustomValidity` is empty (it still *must* be set) then it will [reset the validity of the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#instance_methods):

```
id_('post_custom_selector').setCustomValidity('');
```